# Include tensorflow lite libraries in CMakeLists.txt of C++ project giving errors "undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals"

Tags: cmake, tensorflow-lite

I'm trying to include TensorFlow lite libraries in CMakeLists.txt of C++ project. I followed the instructure in https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake

> 1. git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git tensorflow_src
> 2. mkdir tflite_build && cd tflite_build
> 3. cmake ../tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite -DTFLITE_ENABLE_XNNPACK=OFF
>    -DTFLITE_ENABLE_EXTERNAL_DELEGATE=OFF  TFLITE_ENABLE_RUY=ON/OFF (tried both option)
> 4. cmake --build . --config release -j24

and added all the libs to the CmakeLists.txt file as follow

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(main)

set(TENSORFLOW_SRC_DIR "test_cpp/tensorflow_src")
set(TFLITE_DIR "test_cpp/tflite_build")

find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)

file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp  src/*.h )
message(${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})

include_directories(
    ${TENSORFLOW_SRC_DIR}
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/eigen
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/neon2sse
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/abseil-cpp
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/farmhash/src
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/flatbuffers/include
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/gemmlowp/public
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/gemmlowp
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/ruy
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/cpuinfo/include
)

target_link_libraries(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}

    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/farmhash-build/libfarmhash.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_marshalling.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_program_name.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_reflection.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_private_handle_accessor.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_config.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_commandlineflag_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags_commandlineflag.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/flags/libabsl_flags.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cordz_functions.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_strings_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cordz_handle.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_str_format_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cordz_info.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cord.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_cord_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/strings/libabsl_strings.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/container/libabsl_raw_hash_set.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/container/libabsl_hashtablez_sampler.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization/libabsl_synchronization.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/synchronization/libabsl_graphcycles_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_city.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_hash.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/hash/libabsl_low_level_hash.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_civil_time.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_time_zone.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/time/libabsl_time.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/profiling/libabsl_exponential_biased.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/types/libabsl_bad_optional_access.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/types/libabsl_bad_variant_access.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/numeric/libabsl_int128.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_raw_logging_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_throw_delegate.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_base.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_log_severity.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_spinlock_wait.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/base/libabsl_malloc_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/status/libabsl_status.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_stacktrace.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_demangle_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_symbolize.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/abseil-cpp-build/absl/debugging/libabsl_debugging_internal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/flatbuffers-build/libflatbuffers.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_ctx.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx512.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_cpuinfo.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_frontend.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_blocking_counter.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx512.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_apply_multiplier.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_block_map.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_trmul.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_avx2_fma.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/profiler/libruy_profiler_instrumentation.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_denormal.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepacked_cache.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_system_aligned_alloc.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context_get_ctx.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_allocator.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx2_fma.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_wait.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_context.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx2_fma.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_thread_pool.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_arm.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_tune.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_kernel_arm.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_have_built_path_for_avx.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_prepare_packed_matrices.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/ruy-build/ruy/libruy_pack_avx512.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/fft2d-build/libfft2d_fftsg2d.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/clog-build/libclog.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/_deps/cpuinfo-build/libcpuinfo.a
    ${TFLITE_DIR}/libtensorflow-lite.a

    dl
)
```

It worked on a windows machine but on Linux I'm getting error about

**undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::ScopedSuppressDenormals()'**

```
[ 33%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/ssd_mobilenet_tflite.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable main
/usr/bin/ld: ../tflite_build/libtensorflow-lite.a(interpreter.cc.o): in function `tflite::Interpreter::Invoke()':
interpreter.cc:(.text+0x3ff): undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::ScopedSuppressDenormals()'
/usr/bin/ld: interpreter.cc:(.text+0x523): undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::~ScopedSuppressDenormals()'
/usr/bin/ld: ../tflite_build/libtensorflow-lite.a(interpreter.cc.o): in function `tflite::Interpreter::Invoke() [clone .cold]':
interpreter.cc:(.text.unlikely+0x5c): undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::~ScopedSuppressDenormals()'
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/ssd_mobilenet_tflite.cpp.o: in function `SSD_MOBILENET::loadModel(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
ssd_mobilenet_tflite.cpp:(.text+0x2b2): undefined reference to `tflite::ops::builtin::BuiltinOpResolver::BuiltinOpResolver()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:231: main] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

I don't want to add the libs as "add_subdirectory" as it was given in the guide because it will compile every time I create a new project

So how can I solve the **undefined reference to `ruy::ScopedSuppressDenormals::ScopedSuppressDenormals()'**

**UPDATE:**

if I change the CMakeLists.txt to :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(main)
set(TENSORFLOW_SRC_DIR "test_cpp/tensorflow_src")
set(TFLITE_DIR "test_cpp/tflite_build")
find_package(OpenCV 4 REQUIRED)
find_package(TFLITE)
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES src/*.cpp  src/*.h )
message(${SOURCE_FILES})
add_executable(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
include_directories(
    ${TENSORFLOW_SRC_DIR}
)
target_link_libraries(
    ${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC
    ${OpenCV_LIBS}
    ${TFLITE_LIBS}
)
```

> I take this error

```
from test_cpp/src/main.cpp:1:
test_cpp/tensorflow_src/tensorflow/lite/interpreter_builder.h:26:10: fatal error: flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h: No such file or directory
       26 | #include "flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h"  // from @flatbuffers
          |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/main.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
    make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

Comment: You are using `target_link_libraries` incorrectly. Ideally it shouldn't link with absolute lib files. Instead you will have to make use of find_package for `TFLITE`

Comment: when I use find_package it gives the following error
 fatal error: flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h: No such file or directory
   26 | #include "flatbuffers/flatbuffers.h"  // from @flatbuffers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this repo that contains all needed libs for the project https://github.com/muhammedakyuzlu/tflite-cpp-package

Answer (score 2):

There is another trick that could help you getting started.
Just add this to your CMake File:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        tensorflow
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git
        GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
        GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
        GIT_TAG v2.10.0
        SOURCE_SUBDIR tensorflow/lite
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(tensorflow)
```

and link to the library:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        tensorflow-lite
)
```

This is downloading all dependencies automatically and should make you ready to go.

Comment: Looks promising - can you expand the answer to tell us what the include directories should be under this scheme? Thanks

Comment: (I used _deps/tensorflow-src and flatbuffers/include from the build directory, but there is propably a 'proper' way that would be less fragile.)

Comment: After a bit more experimentation I have found that this oddly doesn't work on some platforms. The tensorflow content is fetched, but dependencies aren't, and the generated makefile doesn't build tensorflow so it can't be linked.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the problem you have is the ordering of the libs.
Try putting the `libtensorflow-lite.a` before the `ruy-*.a` in your setup.