# add_subdirectory for cmake tensorflow lite fails on subsequent runs

Tags: tensorflow, cmake, tensorflow-lite, clog, out-of-source

I am trying to include tensorflow-lite in a project per the minimal example here: [Build TensorFlow Lite with CMake](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake#create_a_cmake_project_which_uses_tensorflow_lite). Specifically, I'm trying to add_subdirectory the CMakeLists.txt for tflite, as recommended.

This works when the project is first built, but if I change my top-level CMakeLists.txt for any reason (adding a test or linking something to a different target, say), then the build fails with the following:

```bash
-- Setting build type to Release, for debug builds use'-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug'.
CMake Warning at build/abseil-cpp/CMakeLists.txt:70 (message):
  A future Abseil release will default ABSL_PROPAGATE_CXX_STD to ON for CMake
  3.8 and up.  We recommend enabling this option to ensure your project still
  builds correctly.


-- Standard libraries to link to explicitly: none
-- The Fortran compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Could NOT find CLANG_FORMAT: Found unsuitable version "0.0", but required is exact version "9" (found CLANG_FORMAT_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND)
-- 
-- Configured Eigen 3.4.90
-- 
-- Proceeding with version: 2.0.6.v2.0.6
-- CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:  -std=c++0x -Wall -pedantic -Werror -Wextra -Werror=shadow -faligned-new -Werror=implicit-fallthrough=2 -Wunused-result -Werror=unused-result -Wunused-parameter -Werror=unused-parameter -fsigned-char
CMake Error at build/cpuinfo/CMakeLists.txt:262 (ADD_SUBDIRECTORY):
  ADD_SUBDIRECTORY not given a binary directory but the given source
  directory "/opt/------/workspace/------/build/clog-source"
  is not a subdirectory of
  "/opt/------/workspace/------/build/cpuinfo".  When
  specifying an out-of-tree source a binary directory must be explicitly
  specified.


CMake Error at build/cpuinfo/CMakeLists.txt:265 (SET_PROPERTY):
  SET_PROPERTY could not find TARGET clog.  Perhaps it has not yet been
  created.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/opt/------/workspace/------/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/opt/------/workspace/------/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

(Those dashes aren't real paths, they're just to mask sensitive info.)

Just to reiterate, it DOES configure and build correctly the first time, but reruns of `cmake ..` will fail.

I've tried this on a couple of platforms and got the same result. You should be able to reproduce with a minimal CMakeLists.txt containing add_subdirectory and some helloworld target to link tensorflow-lite.

I tried giving the add_subdirectory for clog a binary location but just got a cascade of new errors, and at that point my CMake know-how definitely runs out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the same cmake variable `CLOG_SOURCE_DIR` used in both `xnnpack` and `cpuinfo`.

In `xnnpack`, it uses a cmake script to download, configure and build the clog.
In `cpuinfo`, it add as a subdirectory.
So they use different ways to add dependency. We need to fix this issue in either `xnnpack` or `cpuinfo` but as a walkaround, we can change the `CLOG_SOURCE_DIR` in either project to a different name (e.g. `CLOG_SOURCE_DIR1`) then this problem will go away.

Comment: Thank you, will try it out when I'm back at work in January and mark this as the answer if it works.

Comment: Apologies for very slow response. No I didn't, not fully. We have since moved to a Yocto-based build system where the problem doesn't really exist.

However today I've been looking at getting the build working outside of Yocto again. This time I'm trying a different approach based on neodsp's answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851749/include-tensorflow-lite-libraries-in-cmakelists-txt-of-c-project-giving-errors/74260610#comment136287375_74260610.

Not sure what the include dirs should be, but _deps/tensorflow-src and flatbuffers/include in my build dir work for now.